# Why is the first input being skipped

Tags: bash

```
#!/bin/bash

while read line;
do
    cat
done
```

Hi, I'm trying to get the program to print each line given from stdin. Why isn't the first input being printed here? 2nd and following inputs work fine.

Thanks

Edit: I fixed it by adding a `cat` before the loop. Can someone explain why it was needed though?

Comment: Instead of `cat`, use `printf "%s\n" "$line"` You could just use `echo "$line"`, but see [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/197080) And, use `read -r line` to prevent problems with `"\"` in the input string.

Comment: In your posted code, the `while read line` reads a line of stdin into the variable `line`, enters the loop and then cat "takes over" and does not exit.  So `$line` has the first line but the code does nothing with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line;
do
    echo "${line}"
done
```

This is a working version of your script. In your script, the first line is placed in the variable `${line}` by the `bash` builtin `read`. Since you only ever output via `cat`, the first line in that variable is never output.